# C extracting odd digit from integer

Tags: c

I need to extract the odd number out and give the output, but when I execute the code, it gives me in reverse order (e.g. expected output is`1234 = 13` but my code gave me `31`).

```
int digit, num;
while (num > 0)
{
     digit = num % 10; 
    if(digit % 2 != 0)
    {
     printf("%d" , digit);
    }

    num /= 10;
}
```

Comment: of course. since division yields units first. you can use a recursive approach to reverse the printing

Comment: when posting about a run time problem, as this question is doing, post a [mcve] so we can recreate the problem so we can help you debug it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you are first printing the remainder from the division operation in the following statement:

```
digit = num % 10;
```

You have to store it in an array and after all the divisions are complete only print it.

Answer (score 1):

you're printing the units first. So you need either to store the data, or to use a recursive approach so last numbers are printed first:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void podd(int num)
{
   if (num > 0)
   {
      int digit = num % 10;
      if (digit % 2)
      {
        printf("%d" , digit);
      }
      podd(num / 10);
   }
}


int main() 
{
  podd(1234);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

(variation of the classic int to string conversion problem described here: [Convert integer to string without access to libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982320/convert-integer-to-string-without-access-to-libraries))

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, It will output 31.

Coz,

**1st iteration in while loop =>**

num is 1234

`digit = num % 10;`  digit = 1234 % 10 ( It's 4)

```
if(digit % 2 != 0)
    {
     printf("%d" , digit);
    }
```

4 will not print coz `4 % 2 != 0` will return false.

`num /= 10;` num = 1234 / 10 ( num is now 123)

**2nd iteration in while loop =>**

num is 123

`digit = num % 10;`  digit = 123 % 10 ( It's 3)

```
if(digit % 2 != 0)
    {
     printf("%d" , digit);
    }
```

3 will be printed coz `4 % 2 != 0` will return true.

`num /= 10;` num = 123 / 10 ( num is now 12)

**So ... we got our first number 3.**

So, if you continue this process (it's called debugging ) for the next while loop iterations you will find the final output ... that's 31.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer as follows:

```
int num = 1234, digit = 0;
do {
    digit = num % 10;           // Assigns the extracted digit to a variable named digit (ex: 4).
    if (digit % 2 != 0)         // Applies the formula to get the odd number.
        printf("%d\n", digit);  // Prints the odd number.
    num /= 10;                  // Extracts one digit each time (ex: 1234 / 10 = 123).
} while (num > 0);              // Has reached the end of the number 'num'.
```

The Result:

3
1